# Vercel: How to rewrite vercel urls correctly?

Tags: url-rewriting, vercel

Maybe I don't quite understand what rewriting means, or I'm not doing it right, but I'll put you in the context of what I want to happen and it's not happening, if someone can help me.

I have a project created which had its vercel domain as **"example.vercel.app"** but I put mine and now it has its custom domain as **"example.com"**.

So far everything normal.

But now I have the problem that within my structure I have `index.html` in the root folder, that his url is translated as **`"https://example.com"`** and in another root folder called `html` I have the file `contact.html` that if I go to it from another file I would have the url as **`"https://example.com/html/contact"`**, but instead I want it to stay as **`"https://example.com/contact"`**, I don't know how I can get this, if someone could help me.

In my `vercel.json` file I have this configuration:

```
{
  "cleanUrls": true,
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/html/contact",
      "destination": "/contact"
    }
  ]
}
```

And from my html file I go to the route like this:

```
<a href="/html/contact.html">Contact</a>
```

I make the call to the route like this to be able to redirect myself in production of course.

Also, in case it was the problem, I have already tried directing myself to the route in my html like this:

```
<a href="/html/contact">Contact</a>
```

But it does not work.

So I no longer know how I should do to achieve my goal, if someone knows how to help me I would greatly appreciate it.